# Cannot Set Value To FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

I am trying to stop the `DataGridView` from scrolling after `ResetBindings` is called.

I call `ResetBindings` after I update a value in the list that is bound to it.

After calling `ResetBindings`, I am unable to assign a value to `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex`.

Please note that no exception is being thrown.

This is the code that I am using:

```
int currentRowIndex = dgvStuff.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;

dgvStuff.CellEnter -= dgvStuff_CellEnter;
dgvStuff.Scroll -= dgvStuff_Scroll;
bindingSource.ResetBindings(false); // FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex value gets modified after this call;
dgvStuff.Scroll += dgvStuff_Scroll;
dgvStuff.CellEnter += dgvStuff_CellEnter;

dgvStuff.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = currentRowIndex; // This value is not being set;
```

The above code is in the `CellValidating` event for the `DataGridView`.

Stepping through the above code:

- `currentRowIndex` has a value of **12** after the first line is executed
- `ResetBindings` is executed which causes `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` to hold the value of **3**
- `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` is not being set to **12** after the last line is executed

I am not sure where the value **3** is coming from, but I know it is somehow being applied in the background after `ResetBindings` is called.

Can someone help me understand why I am unable to modify the value of `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` after calling `ResetBindings`?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is change the `CurrentCell` in the `DataGridView` then you should be able to set the value to `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex`.

I know that this is a weird fix but it works for me:

```
int rowIndex = dgvStuff.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
int columnIndex = dgvStuff.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
int currentRowIndex = dgvStuff.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;

dgvStuff.CellEnter -= dgvStuff_CellEnter;
dgvStuff.Scroll -= dgvStuff_Scroll;
bindingSource.ResetBindings(false);

if (dgvStuff.RowCount > 0)
{
    dgvStuff.CurrentCell = dgvLEDs[0, 0]; // This line alone fixes the issue;
    dgvStuff.CurrentCell = dgvLEDs[columnIndex, rowIndex]; // I added this line because I needed to specify the current cell;
}

dgvStuff.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = currentRowIndex; // This value is NOW being set;

dgvStuff.Scroll += dgvStuff_Scroll;
dgvStuff.CellEnter += dgvStuff_CellEnter;
```

I hope that this helps anyone that got stuck like me on this. Good luck.